# Limits of a sum

Tags: limits

I am currently trying to find out whether a series can be added using Cesaro means, here are my workings so far:

> $$S_m=2^0-2^1+2^2-2^3+2^4-2^5+\cdots$$
>
> With the linearity rule in mind, we group the terms, without changing their position:
>
> $$S_m=2^0\left(2^0-2^1\right)2^2\left(2^0-2^1\right)+2^4\left(2^0-2^1\right)+2^6\left(2^0-2^1\right)+\cdots$$
>
> Therefore, $$S_m=2^0(-1)2^2(-1)+2^4(-1)+2^6(-1)+\cdots$$
>
> And, $$S_m=(-1)\left(2^0+2^2+2^4+2^6+\cdots+2^{2n}\right)$$
>
> Which means that $$S_n=\frac{2^{2n}-1}{2^2-1}=-\frac{2^{2n}-1}3$$
>
> To find the sum using Cesaro's method, we now need to find the limit of the series as n approaches infinity:
>
> $$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+n}\sum_{k=0}^n-\frac{2^{2n}-1}3$$

Fairly straightforward, although I might have made a mistake :)

What I am stuck on is the following:

$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+n}\sum_{k=0}^n-\frac{2^{2n}-1}3$$

I know that $S_m$ cannot be added using Cesaro's means, which should mean that the limit above does not exist. However, I don't seem to be able to get to the answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: The answer I need to get is that the limit does not exist, therefore there is no answer. So I need not find an answer, but rather prove its absence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(2^{2n}-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n 4^k-n={4^{n+1}-1\over 3}-n$$.

So, $$-\frac13\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{2k}-1}=-\frac13\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({4^{n+1}-1\over3(n+1)}-{n\over n+1}\right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}=1$$ and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{4^{n+1}-1\over n+1}=\infty.$$